# New Zealander returning to Australian job under COVID restrictions - what documents prove my residency?

Tags: paperwork, australia, new-zealand-citizens

I am a New Zealand passport holder and have been living and working in Australia for around 7 months with a 12 month contracted job that, FWIW, I believe will be extended at its completion.

With COVID19 I returned here (NZ) on 20 March 2020 to attend to personal matters, and I have been lucky enough to work remotely since. As prudent it would be to remain here, eventually my workplace will require my presence on site in Australia. Preparing myself for this eventuality, I have found the following site:

https://covid19.homeaffairs.gov.au/coming-australia

As of 13 April 2020, it states:

> New Zealand citizens who normally reside in Australia (with a subclass 444 visa or
>   other permanent or provisional visa) can come to Australia. You must
>   carry proof of residency (driver's licence *or documents that show your
>   residency*). Present it at check-in. You must undertake a mandatory
>   14-day quarantine at designated facilities (for example, a hotel), in
>   your port of arrival.​

My question is:
**What documents will be classed as adequate to show my residency?**

Facts - relevant or not:

- I do not have an Australian driver's licence (I have a NZ one, but don't drive often in AU).
- I do not have a tenancy agreement/lease or otherwise since late last year, I have been lucky enough to stay at people's places since (saving money).
- My contract for work ends early July 2020.
- I can retreive tax information but it will be simply printouts from online sources.
- Ditto for superannuation.
- I recently updated my medicare account but do not have the physical card itself.
- I have been back and forth between NZ/AU with shorter term contracts and even completed a degree there in in the past.

With bureaucracy being how it is I want to make sure I have at least the minimum required, *if not more*, before I waste time and money on a flight that I won't be able to board.

---

I also found this:

https://immi.homeaffairs.gov.au/visas/already-have-a-visa/check-visa-details-and-conditions/check-conditions-online/visa-holders

But as for 'transaction reference number (TRN)', 'visa grant number' or a 'visa evidence number' I have no information.

I simply enter Australia each time as a Kiwi using an ePassport and away I go...

Comment: [expatriates.se] might be a better place to ask this.

Comment: @Arthur'sPass, I didn't know this existed - thanks

Comment: Travel records https://immi.homeaffairs.gov.au/form-listing/forms/1359.pdf or Australian Tax Office certificate of residency https://www.ato.gov.au/Individuals/International-tax-for-individuals/In-detail/Residency/Certificates-of-residency-or-status/#Certificatesofresidency?